# Changing Roles name in Sonata Admin Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, admin, roles, sonata

I am trying to change the default sonata admin Roles which are disabled like `ROLE_ADMIN_CATEGORY_EDITOR`, `ROLE_ADMIN_BLOG_POST_STAFF` ....
to friendly names for the final user like `Category Admin` or `BlogPost Admin` ...

I've created a method in the overridden User entity which retrieves the classic roles from `getRealRoles()` and transforms them.

The problem is that with the `formMapper` in the `UserAdmin` the new array doesn't seem to contain any value.

Comment: Please post a part of your code, which is not working. It will help the others to see, what is wrong.

Comment: You don't need to *transform* them, you should better display friendly names and bind them to the existing roles.